# SocketException: Network not reachable

Tags: java, urlconnection, socketexception

I developped a small Gui application that downloads log files from a remote server.
The Application works fine if I start it from within the Netbeans IDE 7.2 (no connection problems)

But if I start it as a standalone jar file, I get a socket exception indicating that the network is not reachable.

The code that creates the connection is as follows:

```
...
CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

URL url = new URL(logFileRemotePath);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
...
```

The exception received is:

```
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
```

Any Ideas

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you debug-log the logFileRemotePath value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your operating system has a firewall running, it is possible that it is configured in a way, that it allows network access from Netbeans, but not from executing a jar.

Do you get the exception instantaneously or after a normal timeout period? If it's the former,  it means some component between your application and the network resource is immediately resetting your connection - for example some firewall.

Comment: Thank you for the answear.
In fact there is a firewall running. 
But I notice the following:
There is not an issue of netbeans, but of the JRE.
If I run the application with JRE 1.6, the a connetion is opnend without problems. If I run it with JRE 7, the error discribed above occure. 
Any Ideas? Is that perhaps a bug?

Comment: @user2029753: it could also be a bug ... and it could also be, that the firewall won't let network interactions from JRE 7 pass, but accepts the interactions from your JRE 1.6 ... if your system allows it, I'd recommend checking, whether your firewall is configured to block JRE 7 network interactions